# Javascript dynamically determine part of a function call

Tags: javascript

Being new on the forum (well found a lot of answers already) hereby my first question:

When filling an indexedDB with data (using dixie) I want to refer dynamically to the different stores. For now i solved it by using cases:

```
switch (i){
            case 1: db.Reactor_1.bulkPut(result); break;
            case 2: db.Reactor_2.bulkPut(result); break;
            case 3: db.Reactor_3.bulkPut(result); break;
            case 4: db.Reactor_4.bulkPut(result); break;
            case 5: db.Reactor_5.bulkPut(result); break;
            case 6: db.Reactor_6.bulkPut(result); break;
        }
        i++;
```

i have tried different notations to concatenate the number into the call:

```
db.'Reactor_'+i.bulkPut(result);
db.Reactor_{i}.bulkPut(result);
eval("'db.Reactor_'+i+'.bulkPut(result);');
```

and a few more but none work.
How can this be achieved?

My question is being labeled as already answered. That particular answer I had found before and tried all suggestions but none work...

Comment: Have you tried using bracket notation from the duplicate?  `var reactor = 'Reactor_'+i; db[reactor].bulkPut(result)`

Comment: Maybe I should have been more complete. Yes I have also checked the one you propose. i tried all proposals of the one that was marked as answered before (even before my post) but nothing worked.

It seems to be something with the library.

I found an alternative writing in the library: db.table("Reactor_"+reactor).bulkPut(result); this works fine.
BTW sorry for the late reply due to business travel.